# How do you use the result of a function as a Bindable object in Swiftui?

Tags: swiftui

I'm developing a simple SwiftUI app, using Xcode 11 beta5.
I have a list of Place, and i want to display the list, and add / edit them.
The data come from core data.

I have 3 classes for this :
- CoreDataController, which handle the connection to core data
- PlaceController, which handle operation on the Places.

```
public class CoreDataController {

    static let instance = CoreDataController()
    private let container = NSPersistentContainer(name: "RememberV2")

    private init() {
        print("Start Init DataController")
        container.loadPersistentStores { (storeDescription, error) in
          if let error = error {
            fatalError("Failed to load store: \(error)")
          }
        }
        container.viewContext.automaticallyMergesChangesFromParent = true
        print("End Init DataController")
    }

    func getContext() -> NSManagedObjectContext {
        return container.viewContext
    }

    func save() {
        print("Start Save context")
        do{
            try container.viewContext.save()
        } catch {
            print("ERROR - saving context")
        }
        print("End Save context")
    }
}

public class PlaceController  {

    static let instance = PlaceController()

    private let dc = CoreDataController.instance
    private let entityName:String = "Place"


    private init() {
        print("Start init Place Controller")

        print("End init Place Controller")
    }

    func createPlace(name:String) -> Bool {
        let newPlace = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObject(forEntityName: entityName, into: dc.getContext())
        newPlace.setValue(UUID(), forKey: "id")
        newPlace.setValue(name, forKey: "name")
        dc.save()
        DataController.instance.places = getAllPlaces()
        return true
    }

    func createPlace(name:String, comment:String) -> Bool {
        print("Start - create place with comment")
        let newPlace = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObject(forEntityName: entityName, into: dc.getContext())
        newPlace.setValue(UUID(), forKey: "id")
        newPlace.setValue(name, forKey: "name")
        newPlace.setValue(comment, forKey: "comment")
        dc.save()
        print("End - create place with comment")
        DataController.instance.places = getAllPlaces()
        return true
    }


    func getAllPlaces() -> [Place] {
        let r = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: entityName)
        if let fp = try? dc.getContext().fetch(r) as? [Place] {
            return fp
        }
        return [Place]()
    }

    func truncatePlaces() -> Bool {
        let r = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: entityName)
        let batch = NSBatchDeleteRequest(fetchRequest: r)
        if (try? dc.getContext().execute(batch)) != nil {
            return true
        }
        return false
    }


}
```

In my view i simply use the function :

```
List (pc.getAllPlaces(), id: \.id) { place in
            NavigationLink(destination: PlaceDetail(place: place)) {
                PlacesRow(place:place)
            }
        }
```

It works to display the information, but if i add a new place, the list is not updated.
I have to go back to the home screen, then display again the Places screen for the list to be updated.

So i use another controller :

```
class DataController: ObservableObject {

    @Published var places:[Place] = []

    static let instance = DataController()

    private init() {
        print("Start init Place Controller")

        print("End init Place Controller")
    }

}
```

In my view, i just display the ObservedObject places.

```
@ObservedObject var data: DataController = DataController.instance
```

And in my PlaceController, i update the table in the DataController

```
DataController.instance.places = getAllPlaces()
```

That works, but i have this warning :

[TableView] Warning once only: UITableView was told to layout its visible cells and other contents without being in the view hierarchy (the table view or one of its superviews has not been added to a window). This may cause bugs by forcing views inside the table view to load and perform layout without accurate information (e.g. table view bounds, trait collection, layout margins, safe area insets, etc), and will also cause unnecessary performance overhead due to extra layout passes

Also i'm pretty sure there is a better way to do this ...

Any idea what is this better way ?

Thanks,
Nicolas

Comment: Several things jump out at me - basically, you aren't embracing the way to use `Combine` and `SwiftUI`. (1) I just did a search on this page and there are 23 times "controller" was mentioned - to me that's a huge alarm. (2) A search on "table" yielded 6 hits. Much better, but 5 of them were followed with "view". I'm not trying to be critical. But reading your last multi-sentence paragraph? It seems to me that you aren't really approaching things correctly. Starting with your model - and you *should* do that, is the data good? If so, then what isn't being "pushed" to your UI correctly?

Comment: The last paragraph is the warning i see in XCode when using the simulator. It is not a code.
Yep i have abit too many controller lol.
I'll check the net for more example on Combine. thanks